# start powershell.exe inside a ps1-script with a predefined variable

Tags: powershell, launcher

so this is my first post here on stackoverflow :-) hm,... would think i operate with powershell as an "experienced beginner", written some nice-working scripts for OS-automation in the last 2 years. no programming-skills, only little bit of scripting to make my life as sysadmin easier.

currently i have a tricky problem - excuse me in case this was already solved in another thread, but didn´t find a solution to it.

**here the purpose of the code:**

enable a normal windows-user (***not member of local admin-group***) to execute some scripts with administrative rights.

1. switch current user to a user with admin-rights >> solved. created a pscredential-object ($pscreds). works good.
2. start an elevated powershell-session to have the ability to do admin-stuff >> solved. powershell.exe -verb RunAs bla bla. works good.
3. launch a fix-named script with admin-rights >> solved.

**problem itself:**

script-name is not always the same one.... i want to enable the code to use the path and name of current running script `($Myinvocation.Mycommand.Definition)`.

```
$x = $myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition
      Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $pscreds -ArgumentList {
          Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList {
            start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList (-file "$x")
            }
        }
```

how to modify the code that the variable $x at `-file "$x"` takes the value defined in first line?

i found a workaround by myself write the path & scriptname to a temp-file and read it back to $x with "get-content". but i didn´t like this ugly solution and hoped solve this in a better way.

thanks for help and best greetings from germany

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

I think that without getting into a whole host of Windows Auth issues doing that inside one script, I'd stick to what you are already talking about as a kludge - Try letting the non-admin edit that $x value in a file they have access to.  Then run a script on schedule **with an admin account** that reads the file.